# SQL help i need to find the inventory remaining in my office (i want to know unallocated asset remaining ))

Tags: mysql, sql

In sql help i have 2 tables, table one is asset table which is as follow

| id | asset_code | asset_name | asset_group | asset_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 | demo asset | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | A002 | demo asset 2 | 6 | 3 |

and another table is asset_allocation

| id | asset_id | allocated_quantity | allocated_location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | IT office |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | main hall |

now the scenario is that i am creating an office asset management system so after allocating any asset i want to know the remaining assets are not allocated (in short i want to know the unallocated asset remaining in the office)

lets say i have 5 computers and i have allocated 3 computers so i should be remaining with 2 computers so now how do i make sql auto generate this math for me

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What problems are you facing? You do know that you want to subtract the sum of allocations from the original quantity? Do you know how to aggreagte in SQL to get the sum per asset?

Comment: lets say i have 5 computers and i have allocated 3 computers so i should be remaining with 2 computers so now how do i make sql auto generate this math for me

Comment: First you must add up allocations per asset. This is rather basic. Do you know know how to do this aggregation? (HInt: It's a **sum**.)

Comment: no i dont i am still a student could you help me out

Comment: Okay, I've posted an answer. Study this thoroughly. I still think it would have been better had you read on in your tutorial or book until you had the necessary basics, so you had at least been able to try something. What I am showing in my answer is not really advanced stuff, and you learn more when trying things yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get the sum of allocations per asset. You can do this in a correlated subquery in the select clause or in a non-correlated subquery in the from clause. If you choose the latter option, outer join this result to the assets in order to keep assets that have no allocations. Use `COALESCE` to turn the null allocations into zero allocations so you can calculate the difference with them:

```
select a.*, a.asset_quantity - coalesce(aa.sum_qty, 0) as remains
from asset a
left join
(
  select asset_id, sum(allocated_quantity) as sum_qty
  from asset_allocation
  group by asset_id
) aa on aa.asset_id = a.id
order by a.id;
```

Comment: Thank you soo much sir this helped me alot

Comment: one more help is it possible i could create a table with virtual columns that automatically generates me this information

Comment: As two tables and even an aggregation come into play here, this cannot be done with virtual columns. What you are looking for is a **view** (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html).

Answer (score 0):

try like below using left join

```
select a.* from asset a left join asset_allocation al on a.id=al.asset_id
where al.asset_id is null
```

Comment: no i dont know how to explain lets say i have 5 computers and i have allocated 3 computers so i should be remaining with 2 computers so now how do i make sql auto generate this math for me